# dropdownlist using ng-options cannot select the top option

Tags: angularjs, ng-options

I need to create 6 dropdown lists to generate a table result . I've pulled the data and populate into

```
$scope.ScopeObject = 
    { pdts:[
        {a:" ", b:"", c:"", d:"",e:"",f:""},
        {a:" ", b:"", c:"", d:"",e:"",f:""},
        {a:" ", b:"", c:"", d:"",e:"",f:""}
    ]},
    ...
```

My dropdown list 1 & 2 will be something like this:

```
<select id="age" name="age" ng-model="ScopeObject.selectedAge"  class="form-control" required ng-disabled="ScopeObject.selectedAge == null" ng-options="data.age for data in ScopeObject.pdts | unique:'cover' track by data.cover">
    <option value="">-Select-</option>
</select>

<select id="selectCover" name="cover" ng-model="ScopeObject.selectedCover"  class="form-control" required ng-disabled="ScopeObject.selectedCover == null" ng-options="data.cover for data in ScopeObject.pdts  | where: {age:ScopeObject.selectedAge.age} | unique:'cover' track by data.cover">
    <option value="">-Select-</option>
</select> `
```

By doing so,

- *ddlist6* depends on *ddlist5* selection
- *ddlist5&6* depends on *ddlist4* selection
- *ddlist4* depends on *ddlist3&2&1* selection
- *ddlist3* depends on *ddlist2&1* selection
- *ddlist2* depends on +ddlist1+ selection

Doing this way I could not make angular first item in ddlists to auto select the first item. Anyone know of a solution for this?

Comment: What is your problem ? You want Angular to auto-select the first item in your ddlist1 & 2 ?

Comment: yes, but somehow when i remove the <option value="">-Select-</option>, there will be an empty field. I want all the ddlist after 'this' ddlist to select the first item whenever there is a change. eg. when i change ddlist4, ddlist5& ddlist6 auto select first option item.